# Transform string to json in Laravel api

Tags: laravel, api

Two month ago, i created an api in laravel and tested it with postman. Everything worked fine.
Now i would continue to develop, but i can't access the elements like before.

Postman:

[image]

Body:

```
{
   "RFQ" : "123",
   "client_id": "2",
   "ITEMS": [
      {
         "material" : "1.234.565",
         "description" : "Test material 1",
         "quantity" : "2.123",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "2018-01-12",
      },
      {
         "material" : "9.87564.2",
         "description" : "Test material 2",
         "quantity" : "4",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "15.01.2018"
      }
   ]
}
```

Controller:

```
public function import(ImportRequestForQuoteRequest $request, $id)
{
   return $request->getContent();
}
```

Before, i was able to get as example the client_id like `$request->client_id`but now it returns nothing.

If i return `$request->getContent()`i get a string like the body.

What i have to do to access the values?

Comment: what does `dd($request->all());` return?

Answer (score 1):

Try to return it like this

```
public function import(ImportRequestForQuoteRequest $request, $id)
{
   return response()->json($request->getContent());
}
```

**Source docs:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses

Comment: The example is only to test if i can access the values. I like to access the value of client_id to work with it in the controller.

Comment: My bad, i miss understood the quesiton @bmatovu answer says pretty much how you can access those parameters. if those don't work, you can always run them through json_encode

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in you controller...

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function myFunction(Request $request, $id)
{
   $post_param = $request->post_param;

   $default = '';
   $post_param = $request->input('client_id', $default);

   $route_param = $id;

    return response()->json(['params' => $request->all()]);
}
```

Comment: If I return `return $request->client_id;` there is no output even `return $request->getContent()` shows the full content

Comment: Try `dd($request->all())` to see what parameters are being passed to the function

Comment: `dd($request->all())` return nothing

Comment: `dd(request->getContent())` returns the body text:
`"""
{\n
  "RFQ" : "123",\n
  "client_id": "2",\n
  "ITEMS": [\n
    {\n
      "material" : "1.234.565",\n
      "description" : "Test material 1",\n
      "quantity" : "2.123",\n
      "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",\n
      "delivery_date" : "2018-01-12",\n
  \n
    },\n
   {\n
      "material" : "9.87564.2",\n
      "description" : "Test material 2",\n
      "quantity" : "4",\n
      "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",\n
      "delivery_date" : "15.01.2018"\n
  \n
    }\n
  ]\n
}
"""
`

Answer (score 0):

you need to decode json to php array and then you able to access like normal array in php

```
$item = json_decode($request->ITEMS);
```

Comment: It returns null

Comment: so you first check data come from request or not through dd() function

Comment: No difference. It returns still null

Comment: becuse you json string is invalid check theme here and corre like:https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: i see that there are 3 times " in the string. but i have to search from where they are coming

Answer (score 0):

Your Body:

```
{
   "RFQ" : "123",
   "client_id": "2",
   "ITEMS": [
      {
         "material" : "1.234.565",
         "description" : "Test material 1",
         "quantity" : "2.123",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "2018-01-12",
      },
      {
         "material" : "9.87564.2",
         "description" : "Test material 2",
         "quantity" : "4",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "15.01.2018"
      }
   ]
}
```

Change with :

```
{
   "RFQ" : "123",
   "client_id": "2",
   "ITEMS": [
      {
         "material" : "1.234.565",
         "description" : "Test material 1",
         "quantity" : "2.123",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "2018-01-12"
      },
      {
         "material" : "9.87564.2",
         "description" : "Test material 2",
         "quantity" : "4",
         "Quot. Deadline" : "2018-01-12",
         "delivery_date" : "15.01.2018"
      }
   ]
}
```

json array should be well-formed. So try to remove comma from array at "delivery_date" of first item.
and you will get results using $request->all().

Hope this solves.

Comment: JSON is actually allowed to have trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same request with the php storm REST Client. With the same body and headers, everything works fine.
Postman adds before and after the content `"""` I don't know why.
So the error is anywhere in Postman